# How should I add the functionality of another class's method to my current class?

Tags: c++

I'm creating a mod for Half Life 2 and want to add a method from physcannon.cpp to the crossbow.cpp. I first tried making the physcannon class a friend class of the crossbow class, including the physcannon.cpp in the crossbow cpp then calling one of physcannon's methods inside one of crossbow's methods but get the below errors (this is just a few of a the many similar errors). Part of Crossbow's class looks like this and I think the errors were caused by the includes of both cpp files overlapping somehow. Is there a different C++ technique I could use here to call the Force() method of the physcannon class in the crossbow class?

```
class CWeaponCrossbow : public CBaseHLCombatWeapon
{
    DECLARE_CLASS( CWeaponCrossbow, CBaseHLCombatWeapon );
public:
    CWeaponCrossbow( void );

    virtual void    Precache( void );
    virtual void    PrimaryAttack( void );
    virtual void    SecondaryAttack( void );
    virtual void    Force( void ) { CWeaponPhysCannon A; A.Force(); };
    virtual bool    Deploy( void );
    virtual void    Drop( const Vector &vecVelocity );
    virtual bool    Holster( CBaseCombatWeapon *pSwitchingTo = NULL );
    virtual bool    Reload( void );
    virtual void    ItemPostFrame( void );
    virtual void    ItemBusyFrame( void );
    virtual void    Operator_HandleAnimEvent( animevent_t *pEvent, CBaseCombatCharacter *pOperator );
    virtual bool    SendWeaponAnim( int iActivity );
    virtual bool    IsWeaponZoomed() { return m_bInZoom; }
```

---

```
1>weapon_physcannon.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static struct datamap_t * __cdecl         game_shadowcontrol_params_t::GetBaseMap(void)" (?GetBaseMap@game_shadowcontrol_params_t@@SAPAUdatamap_t@@XZ) already defined in weapon_crossbow.obj
1>weapon_physcannon.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static struct datamap_t * __cdecl CGrabController::GetBaseMap(void)" (?GetBaseMap@CGrabController@@CAPAUdatamap_t@@XZ) already defined in weapon_crossbow.obj
1>weapon_physcannon.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall CGrabController::OnRestore(void)" (?OnRestore@CGrabController@@QAEXXZ) already defined in weapon_crossbow.obj
1>weapon_physcannon.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual enum IMotionEvent::simresult_e __thiscall CGrabController::Simulate(class IPhysicsMotionController *,class IPhysicsObject *,float,class Vector &,class Vector &)" (?Simulate@CGrabController@@UAE?AW4simresult_e@IMotionEvent@@PAVIPhysicsMotionController@@PAVIPhysicsObject@@MAAVVector@@2@Z) already defined in weapon_crossbow.obj
1>weapon_physcannon.obj : error LNK2005: "private: virtual struct datamap_t * __thiscall CPlayerPickupController::GetDataDescMap(void)" (?GetDataDescMap@CPlayerPickupController@@EAEPAUdatamap_t@@XZ) already defined in weapon_crossbow.obj
1>weapon_physcannon.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static struct datamap_t * __cdecl thrown_objects_t::GetBaseMap(void)" (?GetBaseMap@thrown_objects_t@@SAPAUdatamap_t@@XZ) already defined in weapon_crossbow.obj
1>weapon_physcannon.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual class ServerClass * __thiscall CWeaponPhysCannon::GetServerClass(void)" (?GetServerClass@CWeaponPhysCannon@@UAEPAVServerClass@@XZ) already defined in weapon_crossbow.obj
1>weapon_physcannon.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual int __thiscall CWeaponPhysCannon::YouForgotToImplementOrDeclareServerClass(void)" (?YouForgotToImplementOrDeclareServerClass@CWeaponPhysCannon@@UAEHXZ) already defined in weapon_crossbow.obj
1>weapon_physcannon.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual struct datamap_t * __thiscall CWeaponPhysCannon::GetDataDescMap(void)" (?GetDataDescMap@CWeaponPhysCannon@@UAEPAUdatamap_t@@XZ) already defined in weapon_crossbow.obj    
1>weapon_physcannon.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual void __thiscall CWeaponPhysCannon::WeaponIdle(void)" (?WeaponIdle@CWeaponPhysCannon@@UAEXXZ) already defined in weapon_crossbow.obj
```

**EDIT:** 
For greatwolf: CWeaponCrossbow and CWeaponPhysCannon both inherit from CbaseHLCombatWeapon and override function etc etc. I am attempting to add one of the functions in CWeaponPhysCannon to be usable in the CWeaponCrossbow class (and eventually all other weapons will also get this added method).

I like the idea of having an intermediate base class as suggested by Tristan Brindle and will be attempting that. Does the intermediate base class only need the

```
virtual void    Force( void ) { CWeaponPhysCannon A; A.Force(); };
```

I am trying to implement into the crossbow or do I need to put in every placeholder function as well? (not new to polymorphism but not experienced either) Thanks!

Comment: The errors suggest that you're violating *one definition rule*. IOW you cannot have one source file define a function/method and then have a second source file redefine that same function again. (Ignoring templates).

Comment: Those functions in the physcannon cpp are necessary for the physcannon's functionality though the crossbow cpp probably has its own definition. Is there a way to separate the contexts and avoid this problem? all the weapons inherit from the same parent and also use methods of other multipurpose classes so there's a lot of overwriting and polymorphism going on

Comment: Can you add a simple class diagram that shows what your hierarchy looks like? It's not really clear from the above what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just `include "physcannon.cpp"` inside "crossbow.cpp". Doing so will result in duplicate definitions of things inside "physcannon.cpp", which is causing the errors you're seeing at link-time.

If what you want is to use some private functions defined inside the physcannon.cpp file, try to move them to a separate file with its own header. You can then include the header in both "physcannon.cpp" and "crossbow.cpp". Alternatively, if the functions are small, put the definitions in the header and make them `inline`.

If what you want is to use `PhysCannon` *methods* in your `Crossbow` class, then this won't work. The best thing you can do in this case is to move these methods to an intermediate base class, like

```
class CHLCombatWeaponWithSomePhysics : public CBaseHLCombatWeapon
{
    // Define some methods that were previously in PhysCannon
};
```

Then change both physcannon and crossbow so they inherit from this intermediate class.